I want the bot to respond to an image with reactions
I want the bot to respond to an image with reactions. I tried this code but it doesn't work:
import os
import string
from random import choice, randint

import discord
from discord import user, message, channel


def get_responses(user_input: str) -> str:
    lowered: str = user_input.lower()

    if lowered == '':
        return 'fala algo'
    elif 'oi' in lowered:
        return 'salve'
    elif 'gamble' in lowered:
        return f'You rolled: {randint(1,6)}'
    elif 'velha' in lowered:
        return 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1229895715657093166/1241841726998446250/New_Piskel-1.png.png?ex=665830fc&is=6656df7c&hm=8cfac1651800f80f61a4c5820b5214605f275a0eb12d56cba42f225315a83d50&'


async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.author == self.user:
        return
        
    response = get_responses(message.content)
    if response:
        sent_message = await message.channel.send(response)
        if response == ('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1229895715657093166/1241841726998446250/New_Piskel-1.png.png?ex=665830fc&is=6656df7c&hm=8cfac1651800f80f61a4c5820b5214605f275a0eb12d56cba42f225315a83d50&'):
            await sent_message.add_reaction('')

For some reason sent_message.add_reaction never gets to run.

You have an else block that returns. The code under it will never run.

@Brawldude2 i removed the else block that returns, but sent_message.add_reaction still not running

There are 2 more if blocks that run before sent_message code. Just check if they are meeting the conditions. This is called debugging. You can print the values to console to see if they are meeting the criteria of if block.

One thing I noticed on the last if block you should be checking if the message content is the link you wrote there. Message.content is a string so the link.

Are you sure that your bot is detecting the messages (or that you are even running the bot) ? I do not see anything in your code that make it seem it does (no bot and intents declaration, no event decorator, no .run(), and your imports looks strange)...
